# asp mvc friendly url routing problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I added the next MapRoute to my RouteConfig:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Noticias",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{urlAmiga}",
            defaults: new
                {
                    controller = "Noticias",
                    action = "Noticia",
                    id = "",
                    urlAmiga = ""
                }
            );
```

And in View, I have next:

```
 <a href="<%= Url.Action("Noticia","Noticias", new {id = item.IdNoticia, urlAmiga="this-is-a-test" }) %>">
                                <h5>
                                    <%= item.Titulo %>
                                </h5>
                            </a>
```

The controller:

```
 public ActionResult Noticia(int id)
    {
        var noticia = new NoticiaRepository().RecuperarNoticiaPorId(id);
        ViewBag.IdNoticia = noticia.Id;
        return View("Noticia", noticia);
    }
```

I would like the generated links looks like:

http://www.domain/Noticia/1123/this-is-a-test

But, the result is:

http://www.domain/Noticia?id=106532&urlAmiga=this-is-a-test

Why?

Comment: Show all of your routes. In order.

Comment: now is like below's answer, and continue like before I changed the order

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have declared this route **BEFORE** the default one:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Noticias",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{urlAmiga}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Noticias",
        action = "Noticia",
        id = "",
        urlAmiga = ""
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Home",
        action = "Index",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    }
);
```

Comment: I moved it to put first as you say, but it not works yet. I put a breakpoint in RegisterRoutes method and I can see it is not firing, i dont know if maybe has something to do...